# How can to change cursor for MessageBox()? WinAPI, C++ (23)

Tags: c++, winapi, clion, c++23

I use:

```
MessageBox(nullptr, "Hello, World!", "Test", MB_OK);
```

But I need to use **SetCursor** function (my abstract task).

For example:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_NO));
```

Is it possible for MessageBox?

Or any primitive implementation with a window will do...

Comment: Use `TaskDialogIndirect` and implement a callback to set the cursor. Seems like a pretty weird interface though.

Comment: *c++23* and *clion* here of course very essential :) possible use  `WH_CBT` + `SetWindowSubclass`

Comment: Your problem is that `SetCursor` needs to be called in response to the `WM_SETCURSOR` message, which means it needs to be done from within the message loop (or more accurately, from within the window procedure). When you're using a prepackaged dialog function like `MessageBox`, you don't control the message loop. Subclassing like in the suggested answer below is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

If you need more functional than what the `MessageBox` provides, it's way simpler to use [`DialogBoxParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxparamw). However, if want do this exactly with `MessageBox`, you could use [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) to take control inside `MessageBox` call and then subclass its window.

```
class __declspec(novtable) SubClsWnd
{
    static LRESULT CALLBACK s_MySubclassProc(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT uMsg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam,
        UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
        DWORD_PTR dwRefData
        )
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<SubClsWnd*>(dwRefData)->MySubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, uIdSubclass);
    }

protected:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK MySubclassProc(HWND hWnd,
        UINT uMsg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam,
        UINT_PTR uIdSubclass) = 0;

public:

    BOOL SetSubclass(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ UINT_PTR uIdSubclass)
    {
        return SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, s_MySubclassProc, uIdSubclass, (ULONG_PTR)this);
    }

    BOOL RemoveSubclass(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ UINT_PTR uIdSubclass)
    {
        return RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, s_MySubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
    }
};

class CDemo : public SubClsWnd
{
    HCURSOR _M_hc = 0;


    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK MySubclassProc(HWND hWnd,
        UINT uMsg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam,
        UINT_PTR uIdSubclass)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_SETCURSOR:
            SetCursor(_M_hc);
            return TRUE;

        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveSubclass(hWnd, uIdSubclass);
            delete this;
            break;
        }

        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

public:
    ~CDemo()
    {
        if (_M_hc) DestroyCursor(_M_hc);
    }

    BOOL Init()
    {
        return 0 != (_M_hc = LoadCursorW(0, IDC_SIZEALL));
    }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND* pccw = reinterpret_cast<CBT_CREATEWND*>(lParam);

        if (pccw->lpcs->lpszClass == WC_DIALOG)
        {
            if (CDemo* p = new CDemo)
            {
                if (!p->Init() || !p->SetSubclass((HWND)wParam, 0))
                {
                    delete p;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (HHOOK hhk = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_CBT, CBTProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId()))
{
    MessageBoxW(0,0,0,MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
}
```

Comment: I need to demonstrate clearly the implementation of SetCursor() function, in any form.
I thought it would be easier to do this for MessageBox().
Is there a really short version for this task?

Comment: @RustamV i paste you solution. about what you now ask ?

Comment: Thank you! But I'm looking for a very concise solution (((

Comment: @RustamV not exist such solution

Comment: @RustamV Its just not trivial to change the cursor for a predefined dialog but you can [write a more concise solution](https://codefile.io/f/KsRzZxnOTT) if you focus on the cursor only.